# Is it possible as an EU citizen to get a driver's license in Germany without knowing German?

Tags: germany, eu-citizens, driving-license

I'm an EU citizen. Is it possible for me to get a driver's license in Germany without knowing German?

I don't already have a driver's license.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Appendix 7 of the German driving license regulations *(Fahrerlaubnisverordnung)*, you can take the theoretical examination in German, English, French, Greek, Italian, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian, Croatian, Spanish, or Turkish.

Comment: you need to search for a driving school that offers that language for the classes and testing, but that should not be an issue.

Comment: Also note the practical test will be done with a TÜV examiner. Those might not speak English. Some of them might be biased if you don't speak German. But some don't care. It would be helpful to understand basic directions like _left_, _right_, _park here_ and so on.